# calculation by adding textview string values

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, textview

```
              for(int x = 1; x < i ; x++){

            int id =1000;
            int id1 = 2000;

            LinearLayout overall = new LinearLayout(this);
            overall.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            //LinearLayout
            LinearLayout llingredient = new LinearLayout(this);
            llingredient.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            llingredient.setLayoutParams(para4);

            LinearLayout llcal = new LinearLayout(this);
            llcal.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            LinearLayout llamt = new LinearLayout(this);
            llamt.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            //

            // ingreident name
             TextView ingredient = new TextView(this);
            ingredient.setId(x);
            ingredient.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
             ingredient.setLayoutParams(textcenter);



             // amount of ingredient
             TextView  amount = new TextView(this);
             TextView amt = new TextView(this);
             amount.setId(id);


             // cal for each ingredients
             TextView cal = new TextView(this);
             TextView calories = new TextView(this);

            calories.setId(id1);




             switch(x){

             case 1:

                 //ingreidents properties

                ingredient.setText("Eggs");
                ingredient.setTextSize(25);

                 //amt properties
                 amt.setText("Amt");
                 amount.setText(" 2 ");

                 // amt propertieses
                 amount.setTextSize(20);
                 amt.setTextSize(20);

                    cal.setText("Cal");
                    calories.setText("600"); 
                     // cal properties
                    cal.setTextSize(20);
                    calories.setTextSize(20);

                break;
             case 2:     
                 //ingreidents properties

                ingredient.setText("Grilled Beef Steak");
                ingredient.setTextSize(25);

                 //amt properties
                 amt.setText("Amt(g)");
                 amount.setText("100");

                 // amt propertieses
                 amount.setTextSize(20);
                 amt.setTextSize(20);

                    cal.setText("Cal");
                    calories.setText("450"); 
                     // cal properties
                    cal.setTextSize(20);
                    calories.setTextSize(20);


                break;
             case 3:
                 //ingreidents properties

                ingredient.setText("Fried Bacon ");
                ingredient.setTextSize(25);

                 //amt properties
                 amt.setText("Amt(g)");
                 amount.setText("100");

                 // amt propertieses
                 amount.setTextSize(20);
                 amt.setTextSize(20);

                    cal.setText("Cal");
                    calories.setText("350"); 
                     // cal properties
                    cal.setTextSize(20);
                    calories.setTextSize(20);



                 break;
             case 4:    
                 //ingreidents properties

                ingredient.setText("Oil");
                ingredient.setTextSize(25);

                 //amt properties
                 amt.setText("Amt(g)");
                 amount.setText("3");

                 // amt propertieses
                 amount.setTextSize(20);
                 amt.setTextSize(20);

                    cal.setText("Cal");
                    calories.setText("250"); 
                     // cal properties
                    cal.setTextSize(20);
                    calories.setTextSize(20);


                 break;
             case 5:
                 //ingreidents properties

                ingredient.setText(" lettuce ");
                ingredient.setTextSize(25);

                 //amt properties
                 amt.setText("Amt(g)");
                 amount.setText("100");

                 // amt propertieses
                 amount.setTextSize(20);
                 amt.setTextSize(20);

                    cal.setText("Cal");
                    calories.setText("90"); 
                     // cal properties
                    cal.setTextSize(20);
                    calories.setTextSize(20);


                 break;
             default: 
                 //ingreidents properties

                ingredient.setText("error");
                ingredient.setTextSize(25);

                 //amt properties
                 amt.setText("");
                 amount.setText("");

                 // amt propertieses
                 amount.setTextSize(20);
                 amt.setTextSize(20);

                    cal.setText("");

                    calories.setText("0"); 
                     // cal properties
                    cal.setTextSize(20);
                    calories.setTextSize(20);


                 break;
             }

            TextView xc =(TextView) findViewById(id1);
             int b =  Integer.parseInt(xc.getText().toString()) ;
             sum += b;

                llamt.addView(amt);
                llamt.addView(amount);
                llamt.setLayoutParams(right);

                llcal.addView(cal);
                llcal.addView(calories);
                llcal.setLayoutParams(left);

                llingredient.addView(llamt);    
                llingredient.addView(llcal);

                overall.addView(ingredient);                 
                overall.addView(llingredient);



             wrapper.addView(overall);


     id++;
     id1++;     


        }
```

This codes runs in the on create method. Basically is a for loop that sums up all the value of the calories
The app keeps crashing everytime i try to enter this page. i tell me a null pointer exception. let me show u the log cat:

```
07-07 22:06:58.872: E/AndroidRuntime(12150): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

07-07 22:06:58.872: E/AndroidRuntime(12150): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.caloriecal/com.example.caloriecal.IngreCal}: java.lang.NullPointerException

07-07 22:06:58.872: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2183)

07-07 22:06:58.872: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)

07-07 22:06:58.872: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144)

07-07 22:06:58.872: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)

07-07 22:06:58.872: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

07-07 22:06:58.872: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

07-07 22:06:58.872: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)

07-07 22:06:58.872: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

07-07 22:06:58.872: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)


07-07 22:06:58.872: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-07 22:06:58.872: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)


07-07 22:06:58.872: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-07 22:06:58.872: E/AndroidRuntime(12150): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

07-07 22:06:58.872: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at com.example.caloriecal.IngreCal.onCreate(IngreCal.java:260)

07-07 22:06:58.872: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)

07-07 22:06:58.872: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)

07-07 22:06:58.872: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2147)

07-07 22:06:58.872: E/AndroidRuntime(12150):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post the code you use to start the activity.

Comment: Post the line you get the nullpointerexception plz

Comment: sorry i arent familiar with the log cat. but i seems after i add the sum code at textview xc it crashes

Comment: Can you tell us whats on line 260 of IngreCal class?

Comment: TextView ingredient = new TextView(this); this needs to be initialized. 
Like 
ingredient = (TextView ) findViewById(R.id.ingredient);

Comment: Line 260 belongs to sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your TextView's like:

```
TextView xc =(TextView) findViewById(id1);
```

The id1 you are using should be in the form R.id.theIdYouHavePlacedInYourXML
I see you are using

```
int id1 = 2000;
```

but you should never use any value that is defined outside R.id as a parameter to findViewById().

So I guess you have a layout file with a TextView and you inflate this layout inside your main activity (I assume that is IngreCal). 
To fix this you should just assign an id to the TextView (in the xml file) and then use that id in your java code. So if you have

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/yourIdIsHere"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="5"/>
```

then this would be your correct call:

```
TextView xc =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourIdIsHere);
```

You should do the same for other TextView's as well.

Comment: oh yeah i get what u mean but im actually trying to create textviews programmically and assign int ids to them in order to sum them up i tired finding ids of the textview and sum its text